# Convert Or(And) logical statements to And(Or) statements

Tags: algorithm, logical-operators

Suppose we have these comparison operators:

```
export enum ComparisonOperators {
   MATCH_CONTAINS = 'contains',
   MATCH_DOES_NOT_CONTAIN = 'not_contains',
   MATCH_EQUALS = 'equals',
   MATCH_NOT_EQUALS = 'not_equals',
   MATCH_STARTS_WITH = 'starts_with',
   MATCH_DOES_NOT_START_WITH = 'not_starts_with',
   MATCH_ENDS_WITH = 'ends_with',
   MATCH_DOES_NOT_END_WITH = 'not_ends_with',
   MATCH_REGEX = 'matches_regex',
   DOES_NOT_MATCH_REGEX = 'not_matches_regex',
}
```

And suppose we have this Or(And) logical statement in a Json format:

```
{
   nodeType: 'OR',
   children: [
     {
        nodeType: 'AND',
        children: [
            {
              operator: ComparisonOperators.MATCH_EQUALS,
              field: 'A',
              nodeType: 'LEAF',
              value: 'abc',
            },
            {
              operator: ComparisonOperators.MATCH_STARTS_WITH,
              field: 'B',
              nodeType: 'LEAF',
              value: 'rfg',
            },
        ],
     },
     {
        nodeType: 'AND',
        children: [
            {
              operator: ComparisonOperators.MATCH_DOES_NOT_END_WITH,
              field: 'C',
              nodeType: 'LEAF',
              value: 'esa',
            },
            {
              operator: ComparisonOperators.MATCH_REGEX,
              field: 'D',
              nodeType: 'LEAF',
              value: '/[0-9]{4}/.source',
            },
        ],
     },
   ],
}
```

Meaning (in simple language):

```
('A' equals 'abc' AND 'B' startsWith 'rfg') OR ('C' doesNotEndWith 'esa' AND 'D' matchRegex '/[0-9]{4}/.source')
```

I need to create an algorithm to convert

```
OR(AND) = (-- AND -- AND ...) OR (-- AND -- AND ...) OR ...
```

to

```
AND(OR) = (-- OR -- OR ...) AND (-- OR -- OR ...) AND ...
```

And vice versa

Converting `AND(OR)` to `OR(AND)` is easy => `(a+b) * (c+d) = a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d`

But I can't find how to do the reverse ?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws and use negation.

Comment: @IanMercer a*b + c*d = !( (!a + !b) * (!c + !d) )

Comment: But I can't use the first negation

Comment: Why not? And which is the "first" negation?

Comment: @IanMercer The leading ! is a NOT, and NOT is not in the list of operators or node types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, `(a+b) * (c+d) = a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d`.
You said you cannot find how to do the inverse. So let's think about why the above statement is true.

This is because the following holds:
`(a+b) * c = a*c + b*c`. Thus, `(a+b) * (c+d) = a*(c+d) + b*(c+d) = a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d`.

But keep in mind, that we are not operating on addition and multiplication, but on logical `AND` and `OR` operations. This means that perhaps, not only `AND` distributes over `OR`, but maybe `OR` distributes over `AND`.

Indeed it is true, that `(a*b) + c = a+c * b+c`. (Can you see why? If not, simply consider all 8 possibilities.

Thus it follows, that `(a*b) + (c*d) = a+c * a+d * b+c * b+d`. So in fact, you can do *exactly* the same thing you already mentioned, but with the operations flipped. Isn't that neat?

Now this means, that converting from `AND(OR)` to `OR(AND)` and then back to `AND(OR)` will very likely result in a much longer output than the original input, but reducing the length of this output is probably a very hard problem to solve algorithmically and I doubt is required in your task.